# Appium WebView always rendered as NATIVE_APP (iOS and Android / Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, appium

I am testing an iOS and Android Xamarin application using the Appium desktop tool (and therefore language agnostic).  The application, when attempting to sign in, loads a webview.  However, on both iOS and Android applications, Appium still sees the context as NATIVE_APP. I tried following the instructions here in case there was an issue with Appium desktop, but I got an array containing only `NATIVE_APP` when calling `@driver.available_contexts` (Ruby), so I don't believe that's the issue.  I AM able to inspect the login page using Safari / Develop / Simulator, so I am unsure who Appium can't see the webview.  Any help would be appreciated.

Note - I have another native application that uses the same login intercept webview, and appium DOES see the Webview.  So it's entirely possible that this is related to Xamarin.  But I have no way of knowing for certain

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the below setup according to appium docs for android.

There is an additional step necessary within your app build, unfortunately. As described in the Android remote debugging docs it is necessary to set to true the setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled property on the android.webkit.WebView element.